# why my table frozen column

Tags: html, css

Sorry, this is my jsfiddle.net link >> http://jsfiddle.net/2vw1035n/

Why my column keep frozen at right side ?

This is my table

```css
    #table {
      margin-left: 260px;
      border: none;
      font-size: 14pt;
      font-weight: bold;
      font-family: 'bookman old style';
    }
```

```html
<form>
<div class="regisContent">
 <table id='regisTable'>
  <tr>
   <td>
    <label for="fname">Name</label>
   </td>
   <td>:</td>
   <td>
    <input type="text" name="fname" id="fname"  placeholder="Input your name here.." id='textConf'/>
      </td>
  </tr>
     
  <tr>
   <td>
    <label for="passw">Password</label>
   </td>
   <td>:</td>
   <td>
    <input type="password" name="passw" id="passw" placeholder="Input your password here.." id='textConf'/>
   </td>
  </tr>
     
  <tr>
   <td>
    <label for="cnpass">Confirm Password</label>
   </td>
      <td>:</td>
   <td>
       <input type="password" name="cnpass" id="cnpass" placeholder="Please input your password again.." id='textConf'/>
   </td>
  </tr>
     
  <tr>
   <td>
     <label for="email">Email</label>
   </td>
   <td>:</td>
       <td>
    <input type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Input your email here.." id='textConf'/>
   </td>
  </tr>
     
  <tr>
   <td>
       <label for="phone">Phone</label>
   </td>
      <td>:</td>
   <td>
    <input type="phone" name="phone" id="phone" placeholder="Input your telephone number here.." id='textConf'/>
   </td>
  </tr>
     
  <tr>
   <td>
     <label for="gender">Gender</label>
   </td>
   <td>:</td>
   <td>
        <input type="radio" name="gender" id="male" value="male"> Male
        <input type="radio" name="gender" id="female" value="female"> Female
   </td>
  </tr>
     
  <tr>
   <td>
     <label for="address">Address :</label><br/>
     <textarea rows="7" cols="57" name="address" id="address" placeholder="Input your address here.."></textarea>
   </td>
  </tr>
     
  <tr>
   <td>
     <fieldset id =box>
     <legend>Terms & Conditions:</legend>
     <pre id=terms>       
Welcome to our website. If you continue to browse and use this website, 
you are agreeing to comply with and be bound by the our terms 
and conditions of use, which together with our privacy policy govern Baggy 
Bag Shop relationship with you in relation to this website. 
     </pre> 
     </fieldset>
   </td>
  </tr>
     
  <tr>
   <td>
     <input type="checkbox" name="agreement" id="ck" value="agreement"> 
     <label for="ck" class='textConf'>I agree with the terms and conditions stated above</label>
   </td>
  </tr>
     
  <tr>
   <td>
     <input type="submit" value="Submit"onclick="validate()"/>
     <input type="reset" value="Cancel"/>
     <!--<input type="button" value="Poke" onmouseover="this.style.background='white'" onmouseout="this.style.background='gray'" />-->
   </td>
  </tr>
 </table>
 </div>
</form>
```

I can not post any images here since i got no reputation ..

Comment: I will suggest to add a http://jsfiddle.net/ and state the desired behavior.

Comment: Please add the css of the id #fname and class .textConf. You should stick to either " or ' for attributes. Mixing it up does not but not a good style. You can edit your code to make a fiddle out of it.

Comment: I can't use any jsfiddle.net since im not allowed to in this project

Comment: Can you relate you question properly [http://jsfiddle.net/4gL2swt9/]

Comment: @Zetoo but you can use the stackoverflow fiddle. But Justinas already did for you. jsfiddle is just a sharing platform for html/js/css code. It is the same as posting it here.

Comment: That `margin-left: 260px;` will make the table to be rendered more to the right than the default. Is this your problem?

Comment: @JoshuaBehrens I still didnt get it, since its my first time to try jsfiddle.net

Comment: @Justinas sorry, but i didnt see any changes in my table. kinda confuse here with jsfiddle.net

Comment: @Prusse i dont think so,since its only to set table into center

Comment: @Zetoo margin-left: 260px wont make it center. It will just offset it by 260px to the right. What about margin: 0px auto? This will really center your stuff (depends). Abhi jsfiddle link works if you remove the last ] . Go to jsfiddle do your site. Click run. If it is what you want us to show. (Login and) save it to send it to us.

Comment: @JoshuaBehrens already try margin:0px auto; but it didnt even go to center in my case hahaha.. *I have vertical menu in the left, maybe thats why it didnt even move to center

Comment: @Zetoo your table has to be display: block or inline-block to get moved by margin: 0px auto. But this depends on the rest of the site. I can't evalute by fortune telling ;)

Comment: @JoshuaBehrens yeah, idk why but even display:block / inline-block cant even move it .. in other project it runs smooth but this one not even bug to move ._.

Comment: @Zetoo I guess you should think about your layout twice.

Comment: @Zetoo Just remove trailing ]

jsfiddle.net/4gL2swt9/

Answer (score 0):

i switched up your table format a little and applied a max-width onto the td's with the label. demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/2vw1035n/2/

```
 <tr>
     <td>
        <label for="fname">Name</label>:
     </td>
     <td>
         <input type="text" name="fname" id="fname"  placeholder="Input your name here.." id='textConf'/>
     </td>
 </tr>
```

css:

```
tr>td:nth-child(1) {
    max-width:100px;
}
```

hope this helps